# how to use Spring-Loaded with jboss?

Tags: jboss, hotswap, spring-loaded, bytecode-hot-swap

How to use spring-loaded project with jboss 4. As far as I've found that we need to interact with java agent in order to hot swap *.class but how to use it for jboss or how to interact with jboss java-agent?